# SQL Server double left join counts are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, left-join

Code:

```
Select a.x,
    a.y,
    b.p,
    c.i
    from table1 a left join table2 b on a.z=b.z
    left join table3 on a.z=c.z;
```

When I am using the above code I am not getting the correct counts:

- Table1 has 30 records.
- After first left join I get 30 records but after 2nd left join I am getting 33 records.

I am having hard time figuring out why I am getting different counts. According to my understanding I should be getting 30 counts even after the 2nd left join.

Can anyone help me understand this difference?

I am using sql server 2012

Comment: You have 1:n mappings?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple rows in `table3` with the same `z` value.

You can find them by doing:

```
select z, count(*)
from table3
group by z
having count(*) >= 2
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want at most one match, then `outer apply` can be useful:

```
Select a.x, a.y, b.p, c.i
from table1 a outer apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from table2 b
      where a.z = b.z
     ) b outer apply
     (select top 1 c.*
      from table3 c
      where a.z = c.z
     ) c;
```

Of course, `top 1` should be used with `order by`, but I don't know which row you want.  And, this is probably a stop-gap; you should figure out why there are duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. You are right about duplicate QC. The table I am working on are not supposed to have 1:n mappings but seems like they do. I guess data QC is in line for these tables!!

Answer (score 1):

In your table `table3` contain more then 1 row per 1 row in `table1`. Check one value which is occured more times in both tables.

You can use group by with max function to make one to one row.